# Html2Canvas problems with thai language

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot, html2canvas

Run this code and then 'save' you will difference of image. Any solution to solved this problem?

Example of code

```js
$(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
  html2canvas(
    $("body"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        $("#result_here").append(canvas);
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data", "the_text_you_want_to_save");

        var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.open('post', 'save_file.php', true);
        xhr.send(data);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas" style="border:1px solid red; width: 300px; heght:300px; ">
  <p>hello
    <p>
      <p>สวัสดี</p>
</div>

<div id="result_here" stlye="border:1px solid blue;"></div>

<button id="save">SAVE</button>
```

this is my result

[image]

( first block is html and second block is result of image you will see a diffrence on )

Comment: ### my js code ### 

$(document).on("click", "#save", function(){
    
    html2canvas($("body"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
          
    $("#result_here").append(canvas);
    
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("data" , "the_text_you_want_to_save");
    var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open( 'post', 'save_file.php', true );
    xhr.send(data);
    
    }
    });

    });

Comment: so the Thai characters are being switched around?

Comment: Created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cf7p5ao/1/)

Comment: OMG I tried many ways then i found this example https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/ and I try to remove unnecessary code ... then... 

http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/1538/

OMG It work!!! ... anyone can give some explanation for this???

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work then i remove CSS class out??

Comment: [The example you posted](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/1538/) didn't work. You're simply copying your canvas objects, which is why they all look identical. You're not actually saving any images.

Comment: please try http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/1538/ still working for me.

Comment: p{font-weight: bold}

Comment: I suspect this effect is an issue of incomplete support of combining characters in html2canvas, possibly dependent on fonts and their variants. Note that the sequence of Unicode code points `LATIN SMALL LETTER C (U+0063), COMBINING CEDILLA (U+0327)` only renders as a `c` while it should produce a glyph similar to `LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH  CEDILLA (U+00E7)`. Also note that the latter comes out properly (documented [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/kywxawjt/1/)).

Answer (score 1):

For those having issues with html2canvas, I recommend switching to the [modern-screenshot](https://github.com/qq15725/modern-screenshot) package. It's more lightweight and offers better output quality. Example in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/x1apujzd

```js
$(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
  modernScreenshot.domToCanvas($("body")[0]).then(function(canvas) {
    $("#result_here").append(canvas);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**font-family: monospace;**

```
<div id="canvas" style="border:1px solid red; width: 300px; heght:300px; font-family: monospace; ">

<p>hello
  <p>
    <p>สวัสดี</p>
```

example here - [jsfiddle.net/chit33/xfj933m1/4](http://jsfiddle.net/chit33/xfj933m1/4)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to double check your image, make sure its uploaded and labeled correctly and trying to full the file from a publicly accessed place.

Answer (score -2):

use https://html2canvas.hertzen.com is very helpful. use this lib instead origin canvas.toDataUrl()